# Alternative C++ web services client library

Tags: c++, web-services, wsdl

I was using wsdlpull library for wsdl parser. But it seems for some cases it doesn,t work correctly.
I am wordering is there any other library with an example of it.
thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GSOAP is free if you are using it for non-commercial projects. Might be worth checking out. I found it a little finicky but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [simplesoap](http://simplesoap.sourceforge.net/). It is ... simpler than gsoap ^^

my2c

Answer (score 0):

Implent SOAP-based protocols in C++ is real hell, i've experience with it (i use gsoap). 
I recommended see to other tools, more applicable for SOAP, such as Java if you can change tool, of course.